# pyyaml looks like is outdated

Tags: python, pyyaml

As I searched for pypi, more specifically at this address:

[pyyaml docs](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/)
I noticed that the pyaml package, previously quite used, is no longer receiving updates.
I was thinking of using it for a project, but if that's really it, it makes more sense to look for other alternatives.
Could someone confirm this statement, and if possible, indicate a replacement for the package?

PS- I am using python 3.10

I searched a lot of sites, but all of them use pyyaml

Comment: `PyYAML` is still fine.

Comment: As long as you're okay with the YAML 1.1 standard, PyYAML is still perfectly fine, secure, etc. If you want to support the YAML 1.2 spec (released in 2009), you can use [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml/), which started out as a fork of PyYAML.

Answer (score 2):

The yaml standard is not that frequently updated so `PyYAML` is still valid and supported by latest version of python 3.

Last update was of the YAML standard was: 1 October 2021 source: [YAML wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML)
and PyYAML was updated on [18 July 2023](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/#history).

So I say its safe to use. Many new releases is not always positive.

Comment: It does not seem to be working with python3.12 as of today. I am getting `error: subprocess-exited-with-error` error

Comment: "The library doesn't need updating often because the standard doesn't update often" can certainly be a good thing sometimes, but IMO it's no so great in this case. The truth is that the YAML standard _did_ evolve to 1.2 and subsequent point releases, and PyYAML devs made the decision to _not_ keep up with it and stick to only YAML 1.1. (As mentioned elsewhere on this page, use `ruamel.yaml` instead.)